# In neural network literature, which one is activation?

Tags: neural-networks

Consider an MLP with one hidden layer. Mathematically, denoting the input as $x$, the output, say, $y$ is calculated by
$$
y = \sigma(W_2a_2 + b_2)
$$
where 
$$
a_2 = \sigma(z_2), \qquad z_2 = W_1x+b_1.
$$
What confuses me is which one is called activation, for example, in the second layer? Is the activated signal $a_2$ called the activation of 2-nd layer? Or is $z_2$, the signal before activated, called so?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A 'layer' does not have an activation. Each individual neuron has an activation.

The **state** of a neuron is it's bias + all incoming connections (weight * activation from source neuron). So that's $z_2$.

The **activation** is the state of a neuron passed through an [activation function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Activation_function). So that's $a_2$. As $\sigma()$ is the activation function.

Related: [[1]](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/11059/what-does-the-activation-of-a-neuron-mean)

---

The answer below seems contradictory, however (logically) it makes sense to call the activation of a neuron the value that is received from the activation function. References to support my claim:

[image]

As you see, the value neuron y is getting from x1 is called the 'activation of neuron1', meaning its output - thus the value received after the activation function. [[Source]](https://books.google.nl/books?id=jJTN8RPgyXgC&pg=PA23&dq=activation+neuron+neural+network&hl=nl&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=activation%20neuron%20neural%20network&f=false)

Comment: Note that sometimes the activations of a group of neurons are called also the activation vector. So, the output of a layer can also be called activation, but this activation is a vector.

Answer (score 7):

I've seen people calling both activation, but **the input of the activation function** ($z_2$) seems more formal.

For example in Pattern Recognition and Machine Learning (the following $a_j$ and $z_j$ are not the same as in the question)

[image]

this [batch normalization](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1502.03167.pdf) paper from Google (where the word "activation" is mentioned 42 times to denote the input of the activation function), and also this [layer normalization](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1607.06450.pdf?utm_source=sciontist.com&utm_medium=refer&utm_campaign=promote) paper by Hinton et al.

Comment: Great mentioning the Batch Normalization paper!

Answer (score 0):

Normally, the output of each neuron after performing the activation function is called the activation of that neuron. So, in your example, $a_2$ is the activation of the hidden neuron and $y$ is the activation of the output neuron.